# Ionic: how to access a Cordova plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using Ionic3, and need to access `iCloud` in order to maintain a users subscriptions across all their owned devices (Apple policy requirement).

I order to do so, I have found the [phonegap-icloudkv-plugin](https://github.com/alexdrel/cordova-plugin-icloudkv), which allows an app to access a users `iCloud`.

I have added the plugin to my app with:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-icloudkv
```

**Question**

How do I user Ionic to import the Cordova plugin?  I need to be able to get a handle on `iCloudKV`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

After installing your plugin

declare  this line on top of code "declare var cordova:any;"

then use your plugin like

```
cordova.plugins.icloudkv.methodname
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try

Comment: kk waiting for your comments

Comment: I get no compilation errors, thank you.  Now when I call `cordova.plugins.icloudkv.save('key', value).then((data) => {` it does not enter the function callback. Maybe I'm not calling the function correctly? Here's the api https://github.com/alexdrel/cordova-plugin-icloudkv

Comment: Managed to test this, and `cordova.plugins.icloudkv` is `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: have  you installed  this plugin in your project directorie

Comment: I run the following, and this does the plugin install:  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-icloudkv`

Comment: post your package.json

Answer (score 1):

use `cordova.plugins.plugin_name` as cordova plugins are exported as window object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. However I get build time errors, when I try: `cordova.plugins.cordova-plugin-icloudkv` I get `[ts] Cannot find name 'cordova'.
any`. Also, if I try `window.plugins.cordova-plugin-icloudkv`, I get `[ts] Property 'plugins' does not exist on type 'Window'.
any`.

Comment: in chrome console type `cordova` or `window` and check plugins property

Comment: I don't understand how this will help? I need to figure out how to access the plugin from my apps source code.

Comment: if those plugins are present in the window then you can call them directly from anywhere in the code
Mostly they are present as in window otherwise in cordova.plugins